# Creating an alternate landscape interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I would like to create a separate view for when I rotate my app from portrait to landscape in iOS 6. The only significant documentation I can find is on Apple Developer site, but it is not very thorough.

I need a thorough run through of how to set up (and hook up) a portrait view controller and a landscape view controller for rotation purposes.

I managed to get it working using some deprecated iOS 5 methods, but it's not fool proof or fail safe and currently over 80% of iOS users are using iOS 6.

Thanks

Comment: I have not yet done something like this, but my approach would be to have a UIVIewController with two UIViews as subviews. Only one is visible, depending on the rotation of your device. In willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: you can then hide / unhide the specic views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following pmk suggestion, I will extend and suggest you to do the following:

In your xib file, create two different views, besides the UIViewController's view. One of them should be in portrait mode, and the other in landscape.

Declare two IBOutlet views in your interface file, and connect them to the views I explained above:

```
IBOutlet UIView *portraitView;

IBOutlet UIView *landscapeView;
```

Now, in your implementation file, you need to be 'aware' of the changes in orientation, and you set the correct one depending on the orientation. In your viewDidLoad you can put:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

And then, finally, you implement something like this:

```
-(void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{   
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscape)
    {
         portraitView.hidden = YES;
         landscapeView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
         portraitView.hidden = NO;
         landscapeView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the code above does not work and is loaded with errors. Lets pretend I am a total idiot and need EXACT PERFECTLY working proven functional code or I will never understand the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Natan. I did everything you listed, and fixed the errors (semi-colons instead of colons, added @properties) and nothing happens. I just get a blank view, no calls being made to portrait or landscape.

Comment: Are you adding the subviews? `[self.view addSubview:viewPortrait];` I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks. Works! (oh BTW, had to replace UIDeviceOrientationLandscape with UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft/Right cause kept getting an error).

Comment: Great, I'm glad to know. I will edit in the answer. Please accept and upvote if the answer helped you :)

Comment: Will do. One more thing. How do I make it default to portrait view? When I change pages in portrait view it is defaulting to the landscape screen showing in portrait.

Comment: You can just add the subview and set which should be hidden and which not.

Comment: Indeed. Works. Thanks again!